# Envio de atributos da Servlet para mais de uma JSP?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Tenho uma Servlet que faz o seguinte:

```
L_sessao.setAttribute("Login", usuario);
response.sendRedirect("InicioCliente.jsp");
```

Ela envia o nome do usuário para a pagina InicioCliente.jsp, nessa pagina consigo recuperar o mesmo sem problemas. Porem preciso que ela envie esse mesmo nome de usuario para mais uma pagina chamada Pesquisar.jsp.

Isso é possivel?

Comment: Mas qual página o usuário verá? InicioCliente.jsp ou Pesquisar.jsp? Mas bem, como explicou o @renanzin, se você adicionou o atributo na sessão, qualquer página poderá acessá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Se você adicionou o atributo na sessão, você pode recuperar ele da seguinte forma.

**Servlet**

```
request.getSession(false).getAttribute("Login")
```

**JSP**

```
<%= session.getAttribute("Login") %>
```

Lembrando que antes de recuperar o atributo, você precisa do objeto que representa sua sessão.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar a variável em um input do tipo *hidden*, Exemplo: `<input type="hidden" id="Login" name="Login" value="<%=usuario%>">` no **InicioCliente.jsp** onde a variável usuario é a que você deseja passar para a outra tela. 
Na comunicação entre .jsp e Servlet, você pode ter acesso também às variáveis que estiverem dentro de inputs *hidden*.

Dentro do método da Servlet que irá redirecionar para a Pesquisa.jsp você terá acesso ao atributo Login utilizando o método HttpServletRequest - `getAttribute("Login")` passando como parametro o name do input.